# Which clustering algorithm should I use to cluster job titles?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn

I have a data set that includes job titles, and I would like to cluster them.

Job titles include:

```
Automotive Service Worker
Community Police Services Aide
DEPUTY SHERIFF
COUNSELOR, JUVENILE HALL
Swimming Instructor
FIREFIGHTER
Porter
Account Clerk
Deputy Sheriff
Assistant Retirement Analyst
POLICE OFFICER III
Patient Care Assistant
Public Service Trainee
PUBLIC RELATIONS OFFICER
SPECIAL NURSE
```

I'm going to clean the titles (remove unneeded characters, capitalize all the titles, etc) in order to make things a little easier to work with.  Once I vectorize the corpus, the dimensionality is going to be very very large.  Which clustering algs would you recommend for a problem like this?  Does KMeans behave well for high dimensional problems?

Answer (score 1):

Use [brown clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_clustering). The implementation is available [here](https://github.com/percyliang/brown-cluster).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why Brown clustering is a good choice for this problem?

Comment: It's quite hard to explain it in a post. Perhaps you need to have a look at Collins's lectures. If I remember correctly he has this covered in his NLP-coursera class: https://www.coursera.org/course/nlangp

Comment: I have a similar problem: to cluster project titles (words separated with white spaces). Is there an on-line implementation there? Thank you.